# What rear derailleur do I need?

Tags: road-bike, derailleur

I could really could do with a hand here, I'm currently restoring a old Raleigh Milk Race bike which has friction tube shifters fitted. I want to upgrade the rear derailleur but I'm not sure if I have to buy a certain type. It has a SunRace one fitted, and the front one is a Shimano one.

The bike is a 7 speed.

Comment: What year is the bike? If memory serves the milk race ran from time immemorial until sometime around 2004, so you're looking at a wide range of different technologies to be compatible with.

Comment: If it's not indexed shift you basically just need a derailer with enough tooth capacity.  IIRC, 7 speed of that era used a slightly narrower chain than 5/6, but not enough to upset the derailer.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any rear derailleur will do.  You aren't limited by the shifters (since they're friction shifters, they have no index incompatabilities) and it's a 7 speed, so anything that is rated for 6, 7, or 8 speed will work fine.  Go to a local shop that sells used parts or a local community group and take a look at what they have in their parts bin.